# Pseudo-classes not working with classes

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

I'm trying to do a simple layout, but I'm having a problem with my pseudo-classes when they are used in conjunction with classes. Although the CSS for the classes works, any instance where

```
a.class:pseudo-class{/*styling*/}
```

is written does not work.
Also, although I haven't used it in the code below, using a pseudo-class by itself

```
a:pseudo-class{/*styling*/}
```

works properly.

How can I fix this problem? Thank you.

CSS:

```
ul {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}    

.nav {background-color: #5F5F5F;}

a.nav:link, a.nav:visited {color: #FFFFFF;}

a.nav:hover {background-color: #000000;}

.chosenNav {background-color: #8AC007;}

a.aside1:link, a.aside1:visited {color: #000000;}

.chosenAside, a.aside1:hover {background-color: #DDDDDD;}
```

HTML:

`<div class = "nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href = "link1">LINK1</a></li>
      <li class = "chosenNav"><a href = "link2">LINK2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class = "aside1">
    <h2>JS Tutorial</h2>
      <ul>
        <li class = "chosenAside"><a href = "link3">LINK3</a></li>
        <li><a href = "link4">LINK4</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</pre>`

Comment: it is because there in no `a` tag with `nav` class

Comment: and your HTML is incorrect `<a href = link4>LINK4</a>` it should be like `<a href = "link4">LINK4</a>`

Comment: So how could I apply this styling to all the links inside the nav and aside1 divs? There are about 50 links in total, so I would prefer not having to add the same class to all of them, and apply the styling to the container instead.
Sorry about that, my actual code does have the "". I will add it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the syntax for what you're trying to do is slightly different.

```
<class-name> <tag>:<pseudo> {
<property>: <value>;
}
```

Maybe you're trying to achieve this? https://jsfiddle.net/yqatz6Lk/

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style all the links than you should give a class and than style like this..

```
a.class-name:link, a.class-name:visited {
 color: #FFFFFF;
}

a.class-name:hover {
 background-color: #000000;
}
```

**OR**

If you don't want to give class name than simply do this..

```
a:link, a:visited {
     color: #FFFFFF;
    }

    a:hover {
     background-color: #000000;
    }
```

Comment: I was really hoping I could avoid giving each link a class, but I guess that's what I'll have to do. I can't use a generic a:pseudo-class, sadly, because as you can see, I have two different lists. I'll leave the question open for a few more hours, and someone may be able to tell me another way of doing it (hopefully). Anyway, thanks a lot! Your solution works, which is better than what I have.